# Help with SOQL inner and outer queries

Tags: apex, soql, query, controller, custom-field

I have a requirement to find total number of parent records which are not associated to any child records.
Now these two parent and child records are from single object called Project__c.

To achieve this, I have tried the below query:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Project__c WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Parent_Project__c FROM Project__c)
```

I am getting the error as

> The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type

can anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: The query you have do not make a lot of sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava They want to find projects with no children projects.

Comment: @sfdcfox. Yes, could you please suggest on how to achieve the required query

Comment: Unsure of your API names, have you tried the following replacing the spurious field and object API names with the correct values? `select Id from Parent where Id not in (select ParentId from Child)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its a limitation that you cannot use INNER and OUTER select queries on the same object

You can use the below apex code,

```
Set<Id> projects = new Set<Id>();
for(Project__c prj: [SELECT Id, Name, (Select Id FROM Projects__r) FROM Project__c]) {
    if(prj.Projects__r.size() == 0) {
       projects.add(prj.Id);
    }

}
```

A couple of things to consider

- Limit or filter the query as it might hit the number of query rows limit
- Filtering will also reduce possibility of hitting HEAP size limit

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is pretty descriptive. You can not use inner and outer selects on the same object type. What you can do is

```
List<Project__c> allProjects = [SELECT Parent_Project__c FROM Project__c];

Set<Id> projects = new Set<Id>();

for(Project__c project: allProjects ) {    
       projects.add(project.Parent_Project__c);    
}
```

And then

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Project__c WHERE Id NOT IN:projects
```

Comment: check the answer below, It takes two different queries and can be merged with one